# Storing sensitive information mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, database

I've an application which consists stores some very sensitive information such as social security number and others banking information. For normal login, i'm working on using `salt` or any `hash functions`. But will this mechanism be feasible for storing those information i mentioned above or is there any easy mechanism to store those information where i don't have to decrypt those information every time but keep it secured at the same time.

Comment: you can use node library `bcrypt` with which you can store all sensitive information after hashing

Comment: @warl0ck : So my point is, is hashing a must for these scenarios ? Or is there anyway where we can store securely without hashing ?

Comment: well even if you store the data somewhere securely in database but can the person having access to database be trusted ? in all cases it is always safe to encrypt the data and never store such sensitive information in plain text